# Do I need Gradle dependency for RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I forgot to include this in Gradle -

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
```

But my project works fine without this record.
So, why do I need to write it in Gradle?
Can I use only appcompat?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7` does not depend on `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7`, but `com.android.support:design` does.

There's no harm in including this dependency one more time in your `build.gradle`, but it's not necessary since `design` includes it.